# Samba + Owncloud

Tags: server, samba, nas, owncloud-server

I recently build up a nas and think about how the perfect setup should look like.

I thought on setting up samba as fileserving and owncloud to access the files from internet. Does this make sense or do'nt they work very well with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes sense. But I recommend to use Nextcloud instead of Owncloud because it is fully open source, faster and has more features. But it's important to use https / letsencrypt if you want to make this available from the internet. Beside that looks great.